# Sprint Planning in Excel

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

I have a problem I would like to solve with Excel but I'm not sure it's even possible.

**Input**

I have several (between 3 and 7) people in a team. Each of them has a work capacity. For example:

- Person 1: 3 hours
- Person 2: 4 hours
- Person 3: 2 hours

Each person can work in one or several platforms. For example:

- Person 1: Can work with platform 1 and platform 2
- Person 2: Can work with platform 1, platform 3 and platform 4
- Person 3: Can work with platform 2

Finally, I have a number of hours to be worked on each platform. For example:

- Platform 1: 2 hours
- Platform 2: 1 hour
- Platform 3: 1 hour
- Platform 4: 2 hours

All this information is in Excel. For now it is 3 tables representing the information above. A simple person-hours or platform-hours table and one to show who can work with which platform:

| Person | Platform 1 | Platform 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person 1 | True | True |
| Person 2 | True | False |

...

**Output**

The output of the formula should be the number of hours that are **potentially** available for each platform. This needs to take into account that the hours are not assigned to a specific person but we are just filling capacity and have the flexibility to assign the hours to different people. In the previous example, the result would be (and I'll start with the last ones to show also the mental process behind):

**Platform 4**: 1 hour - The hours will necessarily be worked by Person 2. In the scenario that Person 2 works the least, they will have 1 hour left

**Platform 3**: 1 hour - same reasoning as the previous one

**Platform 2**: 4 hours - 2 hours from person 3 and up to 2 hours from person 2

**Platform 1**: 2 hours - At most one hour from Person 2 and one hour from Person 1

When doing this with pen and paper, the solution seems quite clear and it starts with taking the hours for the platforms with less availability first. However, I'm really struggling to move that concept into Excel. I'm sure it will take several formulas but I cant find any way that really solves the issue.

Is this possible at all in Excel?
What should be the approach to get the expected result?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Solver in Excel, something like this: (you can add constraints and control to exactly match your requirements).

[image]

Each person was given a "cost" just to get a solution, and the solver was set as follows:

[image]

Note that the "not possible" options were given a larger "cost", ie 99